# How to fix Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

im passing users list as a props to UserItem Component to make iterate on user list and displaying them on table. the list is displayed correctly and i dont have any divs in my render return but i still get the error :
index.js:1446 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a child of .

tried many solutions found online but none of them worked

UsersManagement code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Spinner from './common/Spinner';
import { getUsers } from '../actions/userActions';
import UserItem from './UserItem';

class UsersManagement extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push('/login');
    }
    this.props.getUsers();
  }

  render() {
    const { users, loading } = this.props.user;
    let usersList;
    if (users === null || loading) {
      usersList = <Spinner />
    } else {
      if (users.length > 0) {
        usersList = users.map(user => (
          <UserItem key={user._id} user={user} />
        ))
      } else {
        usersList = <h2>No users</h2>
      }
    }

    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12">
          <h1 className="text-center mb-2">Users Management</h1>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-success mb-4">New User</button>
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Options</th>
                <th scope="col">Username</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {usersList}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

UsersManagement.propTypes = {
  getUsers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  user: state.user
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getUsers
})(UsersManagement);
```

UserItem code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class UserItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    console.log(user);
    return (
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary fa-xs mr-1"><i className="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger fa-xs"><i className="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </th>
        <td>{user.username}</td>
        <td>{user.email}</td>
        <td>{user.phone}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}

UserItem.propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default UserItem;
```

i expect to to fix the warning message

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Most likely the component `Spinner` renders a `<div>` as the outermost node. Check the implementation of it.

You implicitly render it inside `<tbody>` through the lines

```
<tbody>
    {usersList}
</tbody>
```

where `usersList` defaults to `<Spinner />` when there are no users or `loading` is `true`. This is why get the error.

A fix would be to wrap the `Spinner` into a `td` that spans the whole row:

```
if (users === null || loading) {
    usersList = <tr><td colSpan="4"><Spinner /></td></tr>;
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: you are correct if i set usersList while fetching the data to null it solves the problem. but now i dont have loading spinner, do you have any idea of to keep the spinner and not get this error?

Comment: @lironzaa You may want to wrap the Spinner with a `tr` and a `td` with `colspan` set to `4` so that it spans the whole row. This would be valid markup.

Comment: Note that it is only `<td>` that supports `<div>` or `<span>` as a child; you can't just wrap it in a `<tr>`.

Comment: @Andrew This is what I said and what my example shows.

Comment: Yes, I know that's what the example shows, and I know in a comment you suggested wrapping in a `<tr>`, but I just didn't see anywhere that it said explicitly that `<td>` was the *only* element that supported non-table-element children, which was a key point for my understanding (and fixing) my own instance of the issue, at least. So I thought the comment might be helpful. 

Did not mean to imply that your answer was incomplete or incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I had a external spinner component that I needed to inject. This is how i solved it:

```
<table className="table profit-withdrawal">
    <thead className="thead-default">
        <tr>
            <th>Nick Name</th>
            <th>Transfer to</th>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <DotsLoaderComponent variant="dark" dimension="large" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        {this.renderTableData()}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So I wrapped my spinner component inside a:

```
<tr>
    <td>YOUR COMPONENT HERE</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a child of `<div>`.
I see an error similar to this 
You replace : tag `<body> to <div>`

Comment: This broke the table layout for me

Answer (score 1):

It may not be your case, but it may be someone else's. It's kind of embarrassing but I had this problem because I was importing the wrong component:

```
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Col'; <-- Is a Col not a Table
```

Check if the imports are correct

Answer (score 1):

In case someone gets this error and use render like :

```
...

{usersData ? (
  Object.values(usersData)?.map((user: any) => (
    <div key={user?.id}>
      <tr>
        <td>{user?.id}1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  ))
) : (
  <Box>
    {' '}
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </Box>
)}

...
```

two mistakes here:

Box is a div, and tbody needs only tr, td, so remove div or Box from render to be like:

```
<table className="table-admin">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th className="th-a">ID</th>
      <th className="th-a">EMAIL</th>
      <th className="th-a">NAME</th>
      <th className="th-a"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {usersData ? (
      Object.values(usersData)?.map((user: any) => (
        <tr key={user?.id}>
          <td>{user?.id}</td>
          <td>{user?.email}</td>
          <td>{user?.name}</td>
        </tr>
      ))
    ) : (
        <tr>
          <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>
    )}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The problem is I need to nest a component inside `tbody` element!

Comment: show your code and let's see

Answer (score 0):

Alternative with React Portal. You could use React Portals to pass the component to another dom node. This technique works well with toasts, modals, spinners etc. kind of elements that can be used as individual dom nodes outside of the active elements. https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html. Here is a great example how to use with: https://blog.yogeshchavan.dev/how-to-use-react-portal-to-create-custom-reusable-toast-component-in-react